# What's new in Razor view engine 2.x?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm having trouble finding out what is new in Razor 2.x.  Does anyone know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This blog entry is what I was looking for:

What's new, part 1:

http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/10/whats-new-in-razor-v2.html

What's new, part 2 (thanks DavGarcia!):

http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/13/what-else-is-new-in-razor-v2.html

Comment: And here's part 2 of the blog post: http://vibrantcode.com/blog/2012/4/13/what-else-is-new-in-razor-v2.html/

Answer (score 2):

Did you go through the [what's new](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/what%27s-new/top-features-in-web-pages-2-developer-preview) part of the documentation? It's basically lots of OAuth and OpenID, Twitter, Facebook and Google stuff out of the box.

Comment: I don't see Razor mentioned there specifically

Comment: @Jon, what do you think that Razor is? It's WebPages.

Comment: Razor is the templating language used by Web Pages.  It can be used in MVC or even standalone.  The stuff that you mention is specific to Web Pages, and doesn't have anything to do with the templating language used.