# Razor syntax issue with RenderPartial (CS1501)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, syntax

The RenderAction is working just fine but as soon as I surround it with a if statement I get a compile error:

```
@if (@Model.IsConfigurationAllow)
{
    @{ Html.RenderAction("Save"); } // CS1501: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments
}
```

More general question where can I found the grammar for the Razor view syntax?

Comment: For razor syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VS2010TrainingCourse_ASPNETMVC3Razor

Comment: Razor 2 syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10112130/30007

Comment: Remove `@{}` block code. `Html.RenderAction("Save");` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Html.RenderAction` renders the HTML directly into the response, so you cant call it in a code block.

The counterpart `Html.Action` returns a string with the results.

See http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/17/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Comment: I don't see why "renders the HTML directly into the response" Make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
@if (@Model.IsConfigurationAllow)
{
    <text>@{ Html.RenderAction("Save"); }</text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few below (more can be found just by googling);

- [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_intro.asp)
- [A quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx)
- [Introduction of Using Razor Syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax)